# Invoke-RestMethod's equivalent to curl's --connect-to?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to translate a Bash script into Powershell, and I'm having trouble with a command:

```
curl -s -G \
  --connect-to "$HOSTNAME::$SERVER_IP:" \
  --cacert "ca.rsa.4096.crt" \
  --data-urlencode "token=${TOKEN}" \
  --data-urlencode "pubkey=$pubKey" \
  "https://${HOSTNAME}:9999/addKey"
```

I can translate up to:

```
$body = @{
  token = "$TOKEN"
  pubkey = "$pubKey"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Certificate "ca.rsa.4096.crt" -Body $body -Uri "https://$HOSTNAME:999/addKey"
```

but I cannot find an option to translate `curl`'s `--connect-to` option. Is there such an option for Powershell, or how would I imitate it's function?

Comment: win10 now includes `curl.exe` ... i would use that & just call it from PoSh.